# Magento2- In Checkout Page Not Display Payment Instruction

Tags: payment-methods, magento-2.1, knockoutjs

[image]
JS File path : Test\Demo\view\frontend\web\js\view\payment\method-renderer\Webpay-method.js

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
    'mage/url',
],
function (
    $,
    Component,
    placeOrderAction,
    selectPaymentMethodAction,
    customer,
    checkoutData,
    additionalValidators,
    url) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Test_Demo/payment/webpay'
            },
            placeOrder: function (data, event) {
                if (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }

            getInstructions: function () {
                console.log(method);
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method];
            },
            afterPlaceOrder: function () {
                window.location.replace(url.build('demo/checkout/redirect/'));
            },
            /** Returns send check to info */
            getMailingAddress: function() {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Method Html Path : Test\Demo\view\frontend\web\template\payment\webpay.html

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <p data-bind="html: getInstructions();"></p>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now Solve issue..

Comment: How to solve it

Comment: you can use checkout provider for it

Comment: no. But you need to check some core code

Comment: @Magento2Devloper: Can you share your solution here So we can also get solution for same issue